# Obtain the user logged with JSF with Realm Glassfish

Tags: jsf, realm, jdbcrealm

I'm using forms to do a login with a user with JSF, Glassfish and Realms linked to a database, exist some way to know the id, the username of some information to know the user logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean JDBC security realm.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

String username = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
```

Then from the username, you can query the database to get any other user information you want.